# Дядька Черномор

Tags: литература

Помните бессмертные строчки Пушкина:
*Все красавцы удалые,

Великаны молодые,

Все равны, как на подбор,

С ними дядька Черномор.*

Как мы помним, Черномор - это крайне отрицательный персонаж "Руслана и Людмилы", бородатый карлик. Здесь же, скорее всего, речь идет о воеводе.
Так вот, почему он тоже Черномор (хотя, как предполагают, остров Буян располагался в Балтийском море), а во-вторых, почему он "дядька"? Ведь дядьками раньше называли пожилых наставников дворянских детишек.
Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не претендуя на правду в последней инстанции, хочу обратить внимание на ряд фактов. Первый заключается в том, что персонажи этих сказок являются разными существами. В произведении о лукоморье упоминаются оба, причём в разных ситуациях:

У лукоморья дуб зелёный;

Златая цепь на дубе том:

И днём и ночью кот учёный

Всё ходит по цепи кругом;

Идёт направо - песнь заводит,

Налево - сказку говорит.

Там чудеса: там леший бродит,

Русалка на ветвях сидит;

Там на неведомых дорожках

Следы невиданных зверей;

Избушка там на курьих ножках

Стоит без окон, без дверей;

Там лес и дол видений полны;

Там о заре прихлынут волны

На брег песчаный и пустой,

И тридцать витязей прекрасных

Чредой из вод выходят ясных,

**И с ними дядька их морской**;

Там королевич мимоходом

Пленяет грозного царя;

**Там в облаках перед народом
Через леса, через моря
Колдун несёт богатыря;**

В темнице там царевна тужит,

Собственно, общего у героев ровно ничего. Колдун из Руслана и Людмилы  — это просто "Черномор" с длиннющей бородой, умеющий летать. А "дядька Черномор"  — это витязь, живущий в морских водах.

---

Второе, на чём хочу заострить внимание — этимология. По-моему, вообще нет ни одной причины сомневаться в том, что имя "Черномор" напрямую связанно с Чёрным морем, Черноморьем и всеми вытекающими отсюда словообразованиями.

Этот тезис связан не только с фонетическим сходством, но и прямо вытекает из фактов, связывающих стих о лукоморье с Черноморским побережьем. В подтверждение этого предположения приведу цитату исследующей данный вопрос статьи (сохранена пунктуация оригинала, с моими сокращениями):

*"Почему это место названо Дубовым рынком? Дубовый- это понятно, потому, что растут карликовые дубы, а рынок, потому, что шла интенсивная торговля лесом. Но не только, еще там шла торговля рабами. На территории Дубового рынка находился Османский аул более 300 лет последним правителем которого был племянник хана Батыя, который правил в Анапе.
<...>
Не случайно Александр Сергеевич Пушкин зафиксировал такое стихотворение:
У лукоморья дуб зеленый,
Золотая цепь на дубе том ,
И днем и ночью кот ученый
Все ходит по цепи кругом.
Что такое лука — с древнеславянского означает изгиб, излученной реки впадающей в море. Как раз это место является, где Казачий ерик впадает в Ахтанизовский лиман. Тогда все было по другому и Ахтаниз казался как море. А Пушкин был в наших местах. Все что он увидел на Таманском полуострове, все поразило. Кроме этого правобережье принадлежало Царской России. Граница проходила по старому руслу реки Кубань. И как он фиксирует:
«Видел я берега Кубани,
Видел я казаков……»
Кроме того есть стихи, которые непосредственно говорят о том что он был здесь.
Итак Лука-это изгиб реки впадающей в море. Дуб зеленый низкорослый растет всего лишь в двух местах на территории земного шара здесь, еще недалеко от Анапы в субтропиках. И больше нигде таких деревьев мы не встретим. 
<...>
Кроме того есть стихи, которые непосредственно говорят о том что он был здесь.
Итак Лука-это изгиб реки впадающей в море. Дуб зеленый низкорослый растет всего лишь в двух местах на территории земного шара здесь, еще недалеко от Анапы в субтропиках. И больше нигде таких деревьев мы не встретим.
<...>
Далее, «золотая цепь на дубе том»… Почему золотая, потому что торговали рабами, которые ценились на вес золота.
А что это за кот ученый, которого посадили на цепь? Мы читали сказки но никогда не задумывались об этом. Казалось бы какого кота можно было посадить на цепь ? Это наш камышовый кот Хаус, который на данный момент занесен в Красную книгу, его популяция резко сократилась, его можно встретить в зоопарках, либо в музеях, в качестве чучела. В неволе он не размножается, но это уже другая история…"*
Источник: http://otdyh.temruk.info/vse-o-tamani/dostoprimechatelnosti/dubovyiy-ryinok.html

Не берусь утверждать, что всё написанное в статье является правдой, но даже частичная обоснованность подобного предположения, наталкивает на мысль, что если речь идёт о Тамани, то взаимосвязь имени Черномора с Черноморским побережьем не вызывает сомнений.

---

Остаётся вопрос, почему оба героя носят одинаковое имя? Быть может, это и не имя вовсе, а   слово, указывающее на территориальную принадлежность, либо позиционирующее героев сказок как детей моря, вроде того, как рождались боги из греческих и египетских мифов. Вариант того, что речь идёт о тёсках, возможен, но мне он представляется нелепым.

---

На счёт **"дядьки"**, честно говоря, не знаю, каким вы пользовались источником, но помнится, что в старину так **называли старых солдатов сверхсрочной службы**, что легко можно найти во многих словарях.

---

На счёт **острова Буяна** же не существует однозначного мнения. И, хочу заметить, что независимо от его местонахождения, **купцы плыли мимо** острова, что никак не сообщает нам о расстоянии между ним и местом действия "Сказки о царе Салтане", в том числе о нахождении их в одном море. 
Кроме того, существуют и весьма убедительные версии о происхождении названия самого острова: 
*"первоначальное значение слова "бур" ("город", "крепость")
вполне соответствует искомому смыслу названия Острова Буян.
 Выявление архаичных значений помогает разгадать глубинный
смысл мифологемы Остров Буян. Это -- не просто гора на острове,
а, скорее всего, гористая земля посреди пучины (стремнины) Моря
Окияна, где близ города-крепости раскинулось разгульное торжище
и откуда торговые гости -- соловьи будимировичи -- развозят по
всему свету товары -- рукотворные и нерукотворные... .
...В сказочном обличии остров Буян -- прежде всего средоточие
тех самых волшебных сил, общение с которыми способно повернуть
течение жизни в какую угодно сторону, изменить судьбу и
победить враждебные происки. Отсюда остров Буян -- непременный
символ магических актов: он присутствует в качестве
обязательной формулы в заговорах и заклятиях -- без обращения к
Буяну колдовские акты не имеют никакой силы... .
....Самый выдающийся собиратель, систематизатор и
исследователь русского фольклора Александр Николаевич
Афанасьев (1826 -- 1871), которому Отечество обязано
поклониться до самой земли, разъяснял: на острове Буяне
сосредоточены все могучие грозовые силы, все мифические
олицетворения громов, ветров и бури; тут обретаются: и змея
всем змеям старшая, и вещий ворон, всем воронам старший брат,
который клюет огненного змея, и птица-буря, всем птицам старшая
и большая, ..
....провинциальный священник Алексей Соболев записал во
Владимирской губернии множество заговоров с такими
закодированными подробностями о легендарном острове, которые
неизвестны по другим, в том числе и классическим, источникам... .
"На море, на Кияне, на острове на Буяне стоит дуб
честной, на том дубу 70 гильев, на тех гильях 70 гнездов, на
тех гнездах 70 орлов; Киян-море разливалось, орлы крылами
отбивались, когтями отгребались, носами отплевывались от
врага-супостата... ". 
"На море, на Кияне, на острове на Буяне упыри оживали
волос-волосатик на хрестьян пущали. Вышел волос в колос, начал
суставы ломати, жилы прожигати, кости просверляти, раба Божьего
такого-то иссушати. А я тебя, волос-волосатик, заклинаю, словом
крепким-накрепким наставляю: иди ты, волос-волосатик, к острову
Буяну, к Латырю камню, где хрещенные человеки не ходят, живые
не бродят; сядь на свое место -- к упырям лихим в кресло.
Покорись моему приказу, крепкому-накрепкому заговору-наказу... "*
Источник: http://lib.ru/DEMIN/tajny.txt

Answer (score 1):

Стоит помнить, что "Сказку.." писал Пушкин. И ждать от него точного воспроизведения имён второстепенных персонажей более древнего произведения - по меньшей мере, наивно.

Что же касается выбора конкретно этого имени.. Возможно, тут действительно дело в крымчаках (как предполагает [@следопыт](/users/2568/%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%8B%D1%82) в своём исследовании).

Comment: Дело тут в рифме, что на ум первое пришло, то и озвучил, может быть по ассоциации какой, нам не ведомой. Может у Пушкина "дядька" черен лицом был, загорелый такой, кто его знает. Мог и мухомором назвать, тож в рифму, тогда и о карлике можно подумать, грибок такой, горбатый с пятнами.  Море вариантов, можно и книжку написать, почему - черномор, крохобор, на подбор, беломор. Канал для тех,  у кого фантазия.